# R-value for insulating a vaulted ceiling?

Tags: insulation

We're building a finished shed in Austin, TX with drywall and HVAC. It will also have several huge double-paned windows. I think we'll be going with R-13 for the walls. It's generally suggested to use R-30 here for attics, but our shed has a vaulted ceiling, so no attic. Should I still use R-30 because of sun exposure? Do the windows make the rest of it kinda moot?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hmm appears to be too late now, but in hot or snowy climates a roof overhang to protect windows from sun and doorways from snow is nice.  It will never snow in Texas though so there's no reason for cold weather related precautions or regulations lol.  Seriously though that many windows make me think you're considering spending time in this shed, so I'd want it to be comfortable without a mint spent on A/C, so definitely at least price out white shingles and spray foam.

Comment: Darn. Shed builder said there's not much difference between white and black shingles so we went with the ones that better matched the main house!

Comment: White shingles are a large aid in a hot climate, but it's not too late to use spray foam or increase insulation depth.  If you don't mind a pink or blue ceiling you could use 2 inch foam sheet for example instead of wallboard in addition to the insulation between the rafters or reinforce the framing and add a layer of insulation, although you should consult a structural specialist if you're adding weight.  You can put R-13 in, leave the ceiling unfinished and decide during or at the end of the hot season based on your comfort level and electricity bill.

Comment: Tremendous load bearing capacity and volume can be added to your roof by giving up a portion of your vault as long as you have access on the inside.  Currently it is a triange

Comment: sorry I'll fix that later I'm on mobile.  Currently it is a pair of triangles, one large triangle where they are attached to the walls which in the middle are not strong in the reinforcement direction.  The second triangle is made with the small horizontal boards at the top and is not particularly strong because of the small triangle fighting long levers.  If you add horizontal about a foot or eighteen inches down from the top you can probably bear the weight of a second layer of perpendicular framing without giving up your entire vault, adding 3.5 inches on the sides and a lot at midpoint.

Comment: Multiple crossed layer of insulation and stud is also superior because of the lower R value of the wood(~R-1.25/inch depth).

Comment: Depending on the size of your A/C unit you may be able to afford a load meter so you can correlate A/C cost with temperature.  For ~$300 you can get a thermal camera for your phone to see how much heat is coming in and where.  A.C. units also work better if the hot side is kept in the shade, so you may wish to build an overhang for it.

Comment: Another lower cost option than the thermal cam would be a $20 non contact temperature gun or even *shudder* a $2 thermometer.  Measure the temperature of the inside surface of the roof (or with a thermometer, just above the insulation will do).  Once you know the temperature differential across the insulation, you can calculate how many watts/BTU of heat are lost and multiply by your cost per BTU to find the AC cost of that particular R value.  If the cost is significant, double R value to half cost.  Hmm this question is really making me want to make a temperature/R-value/cost spreadsheet.

Comment: @KH I appreciate your help, but some of this is way beyond me right now. I'm currently thinking of stuffing in 5.5" R-21 batts using spacers to leave 1" above. The stuffing of 5.5" into 4.5" will reduce the R-value somewhat, I'm sure. Do I need soffit vents to make that spacing worthwhile? I could also put in two 2" polyiso boards, but that's way more expensive.

Comment: Actually, my shed builder is saying that they recommend filling the cavity with batts and have never had a problem with it. It looks like 2x6 R-19 insulation is commonly 6.25", which compressed to 5.5" is more like R-18. That may have to do. Maybe with reflective paint for the roof.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a bad plan.  You can still hold off boarding the ceiling if you want too.  If the calculation doesn't appeal to you you should still consider measurement.  Worst case the device costs too much but mine will meter a 15 amp circuit and it was only 40 currency.

Comment: You're unlikely to have a noticable "Problem" with AC in there unless insulation is so poor it maxes out the AC unit.  Instead with insufficient insulation, you pay a larger heating/cooling bill for the life of the structure.  R-18 isn't bad, so try it out, but don't be afraid to measure your heating cost.  One sheet of R-10 on R-18 will reduce thermal transfer by about 1/3, so you can very easily calculate the cost of adding a sheet and see how long you have to reduce the electricity bill by a third to pay for it.

Answer (score 3):

The numbers I found for your area are actually R30-R60, so more than R30 would be ideal as air conditioning is expensive and the one-time cost of better insulation can easily pay for itself.

How deep are your rafters?

R values of common materials can be found in this chart from greenbuildermedia.com:

[image: Insulation R values]

To this chart, I'll just add that if you're wealthy there is also Aerogel to consider, with an R-value of R-20 per inch.  It's still insanely expensive so the time needed for it to pay for itself might exceed the life of a normal building.

Thanks to a correction from Lee Sam, according to (See ICC R806.1.2 in the Residential Code) you need a 1" air gap between insulation and sheathing so the following numbers are adjusted accordingly:

Say you have a 6 inch deep rafter, you divide the total R-value you need by 5 inches.  The result shows for 30 to 60 R-value you need a material with an R-Value per inch of 6-12, so you'd need Polyurethane spray foam or Foil-faced batts of Polyisocyanurate.  You would actually *need* aerogel if you wanted to hit a total R-value of 60.

If you have an 8 inch rafter you need an R-Value of 4.28 to 8.57 per inch depth.

For a 10 inch rafter you need an R-Value of 3.33 to 6.66 per inch depth.

For a 12 inch rafter you need an R-Value of 2.72 to 5.45 per inch depth, so anything other than blown fiberglass or Vermiculite will do the trick.  11 inches of Aerogel batting from a reputable source will give you an R-value of 220 at a cost of $1031.25 per square foot.

If cost is an issue to you, still think about the long term cost of AC since you live in Texas, but use these numbers to check which of the materials that work are available to you.  Calculate the cost per R-Value per square foot one inch depth for each material and then look at the total R value you get if you completely fill the space with each material.  It might be worth spending 10-50% more per volume on a material if it lets you increase the total R value.

Comment: No, no, no, you cannot completely fill the joist space with insulation. You need a minimum of 1” air space above the insulation and below the roof sheathing. (See ICC R806.1.2 in the Residential Code) I’m not going to downvote your answer because I like your discussion about installing as much insulation as possible to save on future heating and cooling costs. However, most of your answer deals with completely filling up the joist space. You cannot do that and you must provide adequate roof vents too.

Comment: @LeeSam I stand corrected.  I'll make an edit.

Comment: An easy way to solve this problem is to hold insulation down 1” from the roof sheathing AND install soffit vents and ridge vent IN EVERY JOIST SPACE.

Comment: Now that’s a good answer.

Comment: @LeeSam Put * around something to *italicize* or ** around for **bold** or *** for ***both***.  All caps is for DOTA lol.

Comment: Thanks and thanks for the input.

Comment: @LeeSam It depends.  If you use an approved vapour retarding insulation like closed-cell foam then you don't really need the airspace. In fact, for vaulted/cathedral ceilings with limited rafter space it's not unusual to fill it all up with closed-cell to maximize R-value. You may have heard of the term "hot roof" to describe this strategy.  The only reason for the air gap is to vent moisture that makes it past the insulation.  If it can't do that, there's no significant need to vent.

Comment: Rafters are 2x6's. I guess I can fit 4.5" (5.5-1) then? My drywall guys and the shed builder himself thinks R-13 is fine for no attic, but I'm not so sure...

Comment: @A_P If it's just a shed and you're not heating or conditioning the air in the space then it's just a question of how hot you'd care it to get inside.  Light coloured roofing can help.

Comment: I should have mentioned, it will have HVAC. But also lots of huge (double-paned) windows, which may make the rest of the insulation somewhat moot (?).

Comment: @A_P windows can indeed have worse R value than walls and they let visible radiant energy right through, but this is accepted for their function.  You can think of each different material piece as a parallel thermal resistance protecting your cool air from different ambients.  To figure out the total heat transfer, you know the set temperature on the inside of the walls and floor, so you have to estimate ambient on the outside of each wall and surface.  The greater the temperature differential * time the more R value is justified.

Comment: A rooftop gets direct sunlight all day long, so that can justify a higher R value than for example walls that only get light for 30% of the day.  If you have weak points in your defenses like windows that are expensive to improve, (double panes or high efficiency are honestly not too bad), you may want to add insulation elsewhere up to a point, but once the thermal losses in all the other walls are very low it pays to consider better windows.  An overhang can be a really nice feature.  Even an 18" overhang a few feet above a window can knock an hour or two off the direct sunlight time it gets.

Comment: @A_P `But also lots of huge (double-paned) windows, which may make the rest of the insulation somewhat moot (?)` How do you figure that??! Imagine you were going to Alaska to spend a day dogsledding at -40 degrees. If you forgot to bring a hat, would you just not bother putting your coat on either? Because it's...moot? Consider the logic you're proposing here...

Comment: @J... Yeah that's a good point. FWIW I think I'll be going with fiberglass, so it sounds like I need the 1" space? In that case I'll ask them (my drywall guys) to add an extra 1" of space and use 5.5" R-21 maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Austin follows the 2015 International Building Code and it has local amendments that are published on the city website [here](https://www.austintexas.gov/department/building-technical-codes). There are Austin-specific amendments to the International Energy Conservation Code (IECC).

Before you finalize your plans, it would be prudent to refer to the 2015 IECC and check on the Austin amendments. Nothing worse than following generally recommended standards and then learning that they don't meet city-specific requirements.

Comment: Since it's under 200 sqft, it won't need permitting, so I'm not concerned about city code. I would like it to be a reasonably-built structure though!

Comment: @A_P You may not need a permit or an inspection, but it still helps to follow local code - both from a safety _and_ comfort standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Besides regulations, an easy method for a technical simulation for insulations is offered on ubakus.com

Parameters like dew points,  moisture and drying time can be seen in seconds, thus disclosing any critical layer combination that could produce mold and damage to the building, f.e. the question if and where a ventilation layer is necessary

And of course the U or R values are calculated, which might be important for subsidies. F.e. some EU countries demand certain U values for  public subsidies. The tool/spanner icon next to the result value offers toggling between U and R.

Best way is to open a roof or wall example and change/add layers. Each layer's width can be decreased/increased  and the layer can be switched on/off by a click to instantly see any changes.

The outside and inside temperature and humidity levels (winter/summer average) should be adapted. Here is an example from another insulation question.
[image: example]

Comment: You've posted this exact same answer on so many questions, I'm starting to wonder if you work for the company! ;)

Comment: I did never and I do not work for that site. I do not have any association with that web site, I do not benefit/profit in any way from my recommendation of that site. Exception: I do benefit like any other person on this planet does if energy and effort is saved and energy consumption, oil imports, pollution, health problems etc. are reduced. The many questions (and answers) show that this site is not very known outside Europe. Unfortunately,  not many other free insulation simulation sites with this accuracy can be found - if any at all

Comment: Fair enough. Notice the `;)` at the end of my first comment...